# Is exponential growth/decay always of higher order than logarithmic?

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

The book that I'm reading states that:

> growth of $a^{n}$ is always higher/more than $(\log n)^b$. ($a,b$ constants; $a > 0$)

I'm a little confused as to what it means when $a<1$ (which makes it exponential decay I guess).

Does that mean the rate at which the exponential function is decreasing is faster than the rate which the logarithmic function is increasing at? (Imagine for example $b=5$ and $a=\frac{1}{1000}$)

Comment: Maybe $n^a$ was intended?

Comment: @WimC No it is $a^n$ for sure.

Comment: @WimC Oh well, if you mean there is a typo in the book, then that's possible. I quoted the book exactly as it is though.

Comment: Could you please give reference to the book?

Comment: @DavidScholz The book isn't in English so I guess it wouldn't be of any help I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the book might have had a typo because while it is true that an exponential always grows faster than any logarithm, that should only be true when $a > 1$

Comment: Yes that should be the case otherwise it wouldn't make any sense.